# Stuck for over 2 months getting an outlook addin to work

Tags: outlook, add-in

This is basically a re-post of a previous question, but I've spent over 2 months stuck on this same issue and I haven't made any progress of any kind. Long story short, sometimes it fires and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it loads once, sometimes Outlook defaults it to "inactive" and there's nothing I seem to be able to do about it. When it DOES fire, it hangs up when trying to send the first email. So, I have old appointments outside of the date range I'm checking and the messagebox appears for those. When it gets to "new" appointments (within the date range), sometimes it pops up the first messagebox but hangs up trying to send the email. SOmetimes that first "good" messagebox fails to pop up. The last advice I got regarding this issue was to build a log file, but I couldn't figure out how/what good it was going to do me or honestly I wasn't even sure what I was going to need to log, and the gentleman who suggested it never responded to me when I asked. Thank you in advance for your help, this is easily one of the most frustrating things I've ever run in to as a developer.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    //Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        doStuff();
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268866.aspx

    private void doStuff()
    {
        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
        Thread.Sleep(30000); //120 seconds - was 120000

        DateTime firstRun = DateTime.Now; //So we can check every 24 hours? Maybe once initially as well.
        DateTime lastRun = DateTime.Now;//.AddHours(1); //We're going to compare this to firstRun
        bool whileTrue = true;
        //int test = 0;

        try
        {
            while (whileTrue)
            {
                if (whileTrue == true)//(firstRun > lastRun.AddDays(1))
                {
                    Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
                    Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
                    outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true; //was true

                    List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> lst = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();

                    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
                    {
                        lst.Add(item);
                        //We can probably just handle logic in here without the second for loop that comes next
                    }

                    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem x in lst)
                    {
                        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
                        DateTime apptDate = x.Start;

                        if (x.Subject.ToLower().Contains("telos"))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("X: " + x.Start + "XYZ: " + x.Subject);

                            if (x.Start > startDate && x.Start < endDate)
                            {

                                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = app.CreateItem((OlItemType.olMailItem));


                                //Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                                //Outlook.Recipient recipient = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CreateRecipient("cindy@soundstewardship.com");
                                //email.Sender = recipient.AddressEntry;


                                //Outlook.Recipient recipient = app.Session.CreateRecipient("someone@example.com");
                                //email.Sender = recipient.AddressEntry;
                                //email.SentOnBehalfOfName = "someone@example.com";
                                email.Display(true); //was false
                                email.Subject = "You have a new appointment";
                                email.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
                                email.To = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address; //Current email address.
                                email.Body = "This email was automatically generated to remind you have an upcoming appointment on: " + x.Start.ToString();
                                email.Save();
                                email.Close(OlInspectorClose.olSave);
                                //((Outlook._MailItem)email).Send();
                                //email.Send();
                                //((Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Send();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    lastRun = DateTime.Now;
                    whileTrue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    /*
                    Outlook.MailItem email = new Outlook.MailItem();
                    email.Subject = "This is only a test.";
                    email.To = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address; //Current email address.
                    email.Body = "This is only a test.";
                    //email.Send();
                    ((Outlook._MailItem)email).Send();
                     * */
                }




            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e) //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception e
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            app.Quit();
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the code. You need to use the Application property of the add-in class.

> At startup, I need it to read all appointments whose subject contains a certain string

Don't use the foreach for iterating over all items in the folder. Instead, you need to use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class. You may read more about these methods in the following articles (the sample code is included):

[How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)

[How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

When you are done I'd recommend using the [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862796(v=office.15).aspx) or [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Recipient(s) class to resolve all recipients against the address book.

> Also, like 75% of the time this addin loads directly as "inactive" and doesn't fire.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Also Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric. For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold. See [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I'm in the process of trying to implement this. I can't seem to find how to include a subject that contains in my search string: string searchCriteria = "[Start]< =\"" + endDate + "\"" + " AND [End]>=\"" + endDate + "\""; .... I need these two AND subject contains "teststring" and I can't seem to find the contains operator that i"d need to use?  In the meantime, I'm trying to use .contains on the apptItem to see if I can do it that way.

Comment: See [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866013.aspx).

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help. For some reason the find/findnext didn't work but the restrict worked beautifully, and my addin is almost done. You guys are awesome!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you sleep on the main Outlook thread? And then loop through *all* items in the folder instead of using Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext?

Comment: That's a great question. I have no idea, I've never written an outlook plugin before and the documentation I looked at didn't help me much. To say I don't know what I'm doing is an understatement.

Comment: Use "@SQL" syntax for your queries - take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, Dmitry.